# How do you hide a field set?

Tags: c#, javascript

```
fsCreditCard.Visible = false;
```

works in some of the code-behind c# code to hide the fieldset, fsCreditCard,  defined in .aspx code like this:

```
<fieldset id="fsCreditCard" runat="server" visible="false">
    <legend>Credit Card</legend>
        <ul style="margin:50px;font-size:16px;">
            <li>
                <u><b><a href="javascript:OpenPaymentWindow(); fsCreditCard.Visible= false; fsAfterCreditCard.Visible = true; fsPaymentOptions.Visible=false;">Click here</a></b></u> now to open the PayPal payment window and complete your payment. If you have any trouble, please make sure any pop up blockers are disabled and reload this page.<br /><br />
            </li>
        </ul>
</fieldset>
```

Now, when the user clicks on the hyperlink "Click Here", the "OpenPaymentWindow actually is processed but the "fsCreditCard.Visible= false; fsAfterCreditCard.Visible = true;" commands are not done.  They do not seem to be javascript commands and they exist elsewhere in C# code.  What do you suggest?

Comment: Probably you need `element.style.visibility = 'visible'; (or 'hidden')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the logic to show/hide elements into the `OpenPaymentWindow` JavaScript function and use jQuery selectors, like this:

```
function OpenPaymentWindow() {
    // Logic to open payment window here

    // Show/hide DOM elements here
    $('#fsCreditCard').hide();
    $('#fsAfterCreditCard').show();
    $('#fsPaymentOptions').hide();
}
```